# How to create a recursive linked node insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

Here's what Ive figured out till now but I'm confused as to what I have to do next.

```
@d <= lnk.value:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'LinkNode'
```

Comment: What errors? Please include the full traceback.

Comment: In addition to what @roganjosh asked, please [edit] your question to include it there, not here in the comments.

Comment: Hey IneedHelpFellas! 
In case you're really new to python, the "Full Traceback" is the error report that shows up when you try to run the code. Posting this as part of your code can help us determine what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, for the not adding that beforehand, just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
File "D:/insertionsort.py", line 21, in insert
    if lnk == None or val.value <= lnk.value:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'LinkNode'
```

Is telling you that when `<=` gets called, `lnk.value` is a `LinkNode`, which
can't be compared with an `int` (which is what `val.value` is). In the line:

```
lnkNew = LinkNode(lnk, insert(val, lnk.rest))
```

You're setting `lnkNew.value` to `lnk`; it should be `lnk.value`.

Comment: yes, that would work if the frozen was false, but in case of frozen to be true,i cant really change the lnk

Comment: @IneedHelpFellas I mean that when you build the new `LinkNode`, you should be using `lnk.value` to initialise `value` in `lnkNew`.